# Grep unnamed column for row indices

Tags: r, readxl

We receive a monthly report in excel format where I only need specific values. Previously, I was able to use readxl to grep the desired column for the row numbers and go from there:

```
library(readxl)
file <- read_excel(readxl_example("deaths.xlsx"), col_names = FALSE)) 
row_pos <- grep(pattern = "actor", file$..2)
```

I could then grep some more for the specific column I wanted:

```
col_pos <- grep(pattern = "Has Kids", file)
```

This used to return the row positions I wanted, I could extract and proceed to munge my data.

I am intentionally using the **now** incorrect `$..2` syntax here. A recent update changed this convention to `$...2`

My question is how to implement a more robust selection for the first `grep`, so that I don't have to update all my code when a minor syntax change in readxl (or any other package) is implemented?

I have tried:

```
row_pos <- grep(pattern = "actor", x = file %>% select(contains("2")))
```

But that only returns the first value.

Here's the rest of the pipeline for some context on what happens to the data.

```
values <- as.data.frame(t(file[row_pos, col_pos]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
```

etc. 
Thanks!

Comment: The function `names(file)` can be used to retrieve the column names.  Then something like `file[[grep("2", names(file))]]` would select the correct column(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague suggested using dplyr::pull, which pulls out the values as a vector. This is useful for unstructured data where you're really grepping around for the values you want and then rewrangling them into the right format.

```
row_pos <- grep(pattern = "actor", pull(data[,2]))
```

thanks all!